# Oracle recursive query with only one column

Tags: oracle, recursion

I've a table `leg` with a date column `datainizio` which has rows:

```
23-MAR-18
15-MAR-13
```

I must verify is an external date is between sysdate and 23-mar-18 or 22-mar-18 and 15-mar-13. Those dates are from table `par` which has:

```
02-APR-18
04-MAR-17
17-MAR-16
```

Result I'm trying to get:

```
range                   count
----------------------  -----
23-MAR-18 - sysdate         1
15-MAR-13 - 22-MAR-18       2
```

Is possible to do this with recursion?

Comment: Why do you need (or want) recursion - why can't you just compare against both dates? It would help if you explained what you mean by verify - what result are you expecting from some sample external dates, and how will those be supplied?

Comment: Pending clarification, [here's a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d3e19/3) that might give you some ideas. (Too many guesses to make it an answer...)

Comment: This will be a piece of a bigger function. I don't want use necessary the recursion but it had seemed to me the best idea. How can I take both dates? Naturally, in the table, now there are two tuples but they could be more

Comment: There is another table (par) with a lot of tuples with a date filed data.
For example
02-apr-18
04-mar-17
17-mar-16.
I must token a date of data and check if this date in beteween the range sysdate and 23-mar-18 or 22-mar-18 and 15-mar-13 and other possibile range

Comment: I must check all dates in the field data and verify and count how many dates are in a range

Comment: Show some sample data rows of the tables involved and describe what exactly you are trying to do in the question and also include the expected result. Present it only in text format, no images. Don't add any more details in the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generates the ranges using the lead function:

```
select datainizio as date_from,
  coalesce(lead(datainizio) over (order by datainizio), sysdate) as date_to
from leg;

DATE_FROM  DATE_TO   
---------- ----------
2013-03-15 2018-03-23
2018-03-23 2018-06-28
```

and then treat that as a CTE and use a left outer join to the `par` table to count matches based on the range:

```
with ranges as (
  select datainizio as date_from,
    coalesce(lead(datainizio) over (order by datainizio), sysdate) as date_to
  from leg
)
select r.date_from, r.date_to - 1/86400 as date_to, count(p.datainizio)
from ranges r
left join par p
on p.datainizio >= r.date_from
and p.datainizio < r.date_to
group by r.date_from, r.date_to
order by r.date_from;

DATE_FROM  DATE_TO    COUNT(P.DATAINIZIO)
---------- ---------- -------------------
2013-03-15 2018-03-22                   2
2018-03-23 2018-06-28                   1
```

I'm adjusting the date-to value back by a second to get the values (other than sysdate) to be the day before. If the `par` dates all have time as midnight then you could do that in the CTE instead, taking off a day there. (This also assume it will run after midnight today).

If you want to see the ranges as strings as you have shown, with `sysdate` as a word, you can modify the CTE slightly and use string concatenation:

```
with ranges as (
  select datainizio as date_from,
    lead(datainizio) over (order by datainizio) as date_to
  from leg
)
select to_char(r.date_from, 'DD-MON-RR') || ' - ' ||
  case when date_to is null then 'sysdate'
       else to_char(date_to - 1/86400, 'DD-MON-RR')
  end as range,
  count(p.datainizio)
from ranges r
left join par p
on p.datainizio >= r.date_from
and p.datainizio < coalesce(r.date_to, sysdate)
group by r.date_from, r.date_to
order by r.date_from;

RANGE                 COUNT(P.DATAINIZIO)
--------------------- -------------------
15-MAR-13 - 22-MAR-18                   2
23-MAR-18 - sysdate                     1
```

[db<>fiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fe6451dacb18356a6530ddbfc95fc6ce)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, unfortunately, my oracle's version (11g), when I try the first part of your code in a view, returns this error: "The SQL syntax is valid, however the query is invalid or uses functionality that is not supported.

Unknown error(s) parsing SQL: 6 "
I hope I did not do something wrong

Comment: I tested this in11gR2, I'm not doing anything unusual. That error isn't coming from Oracle though - looks like your client is parsing the statement itself and doesn't like it. The message isn't helpful... Which client and version are you using, out of interest? Can you run the statement directly, without trying to create a view from it?

Comment: Thanks, alex. Your solution is excellent. I answer now because I had some problems with oracle (I don't now very well this system).
Thanks a lot again